# TikZ Adding Text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a recent convert to TikZ from `xy-pic`, and am still trying to get a hang for it. I see that one can add labels to the end of arrows and the like using `\node`. Is there a way to add an arbitrary piece of text at a given position in the drawing, regardless of whether there is a shape there, a line there, or nothing at all? Thanks very much for your insight.

Comment: What do you mean with `an arbitrary position in the text`? Do you mean at an arbitrary position in your drawing, specified using a coordinate system? Or do you mean at a certain place in your LaTeX document?

Comment: Sorry, I mean at an arbitrary position within the drawing itself, preferably specified by coordinates. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, then using the `\node at (<x>,<y>) {<text>}` syntax as in Gonzalo's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

In TikZ you can use nodes to place almost anything (in particular, text) in the position you want. In the following example I used the `at` construct to specify the exact position of the nodes using explicit coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0,0) {some text};
\node[draw,align=left] at (3,0) {some text\\ spanning three lines\\ with manual line breaks};
\node[draw,text width=4cm] at (2,-2) {some text spanning three lines with automatic line breaks};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I only used the `draw` option to make the nodes visible. Notice that in the second `\node` I used the  `align=` key and then used the `\\` command to enforce the line breaks at the desired positions. In the third `\node`, instead of specifying the line breaks "manually", I specified a width for the text and now the line breaking was made automatically.

[image]

Comment: This is great, many thanks. For some reason, though, I get an error in trying to compile across the line containing "align=left". Any ideas on why this is? If I remove that, the picture compiles fine, although the line breaks are ignored. Hmm...

Comment: @Skeptic: Seems that you are using an outdated version of PGF. Add `\pgfversion` to your code, and after compilation, you will see in your document the PGF version that your system is using. If your version number is less than `2.10` then you should update it.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow calculate the coordinates of a point on the edge of the boxes, maybe in percents or some other relative units, a point like the center of the "right border" of some box?

I want to create arrows with it from one box to the next.

Comment: +1 to @GalGrünfeld for the text placement question. Hopefully an answer will magically appear.

Comment: +1. If I do not want to add the box around the text, I can use "\node[] at (0,0) {some text};" instead. Yes? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to get rid off the box?

Comment: @user1700890 Just change `\node[draw` to `\node[` (i.e. remove the `draw`). See [explanation here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170645/removing-bounding-box-of-text-node-tikz).

Comment: I added a plot and the coordinates do not line up.  Any suggestions to get them to line up, so I can put a node with text at a point directle on the graph?

Comment: I just discovered that if you do not add `align=left` as the `\draw` parameter, the linebreak `\\\` will not work.