# Removing bounding box of text node (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

When I added some text into my Tikz figure, it also hows the bounding box how can I get rid of it. (I took the example from: [TikZ Adding Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/tikz-adding-text))

[image]

Here is what I've got:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]

\draw (0,1.3) node[below] {$B$} --
(3,1.3) node[below] {$C$} --
(1.5,4.3) node[above] {$A$} -- cycle;
\draw (1.5,4.3) -- (1.5,1.3) node[below] {$D$};
\draw (1.5,1.5) -- (1.7,1.5) -- (1.7,1.3);
\node[draw,text width=3cm] at (4.5,4) {some text spanning three lines with automatic line breaks};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Remove the `draw` key from the `node` options list.

Comment: Please add a solution to this question and accept it, if it fits to your needs, so this post can be closed automatically.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The `draw` key in the options list for the node tells TikZ to draw the node shape around the node. And the default node shape is `rectangle`. So this is why the node is boxed using the `draw` key.

Remove the `draw` key from the `node` options to not draw the node:

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,1.3) node[below] {$B$} -- (3,1.3) node[below] {$C$} -- 
    (1.5,4.3) node[above] {$A$} -- cycle;
  \draw (1.5,4.3) -- (1.5,1.3) node[below] {$D$};
  \draw (1.5,1.5) -- (1.7,1.5) -- (1.7,1.3);
  \node[text width=3cm] at (4.5,4) 
    {some text spanning three lines with automatic line breaks};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Is there an option to fit the text inside the boundaries of a rectangle given by, say (3,3) and (6,7)?