# Tikz: vertical/horizontal align rotated text in a box coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Assume I have a coordinate of a rectangle (x,y,height,width or 2 points).

Now I want to center text both **horizontal/vertical rotated** **automatically**, with keeping in mind text properties (eg **font-size/bold**).

Off course I can do this manual (trail and error) but then I should do it manually again if the box changes (and the box is in reality derived from papersize/margins/etc).

This box is only for "debug" purpose. In the end it should be able to remove/make the box invisible.

**MWE + Screenshot:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\X{4}
\def\Y{4}
\def\WIDTH{2}
\def\HEIGHT{15}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% "debug" box
\draw (\X,\Y) -- (\X+\WIDTH,\Y) -- (\X+\WIDTH,\Y+\HEIGHT) -- (\X,\Y+\HEIGHT) -- (\X,\Y);
% How to get this automatically centered vertically/horizontally in the box?
\node[rotate=270,font=\bf] at (\X, \Y)   (a) {\Huge center horz/vert in box?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**This MWE produces:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why so complicated? Just place a node, use `draw` to draw the rectangle around it, or omit it to remove the rectangle.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\X{4}%
\def\Y{4}%
\def\WIDTH{2}%
\def\HEIGHT{15}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rotate=270, minimum height=\WIDTH cm, minimum width=\HEIGHT cm] at (\X, \Y) {\bfseries\Huge Centered text in box};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: Nice job. Your code is very easy and clear.

Comment: @robert no problem

Comment: Is there a way to hide the bounding box?

Comment: @zionpi remove `draw`. See also this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170731/69578).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the lower left corner of the rectangle, the following example puts the node at the middle of the rectangle. There, the anchor of the node is placed, which is the center of the node:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\X{4}
\def\Y{4}
\def\WIDTH{2}
\def\HEIGHT{15}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % "debug" box
  \draw (\X,\Y) rectangle (\X+\WIDTH,\Y+\HEIGHT);

  \path
    (\X, \Y) --
    node[
      rotate=270,
      anchor=center,
      font=\bfseries\Huge,
    ] {Centered text in box}
    (\X + \WIDTH, \Y + \HEIGHT)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]