# Not to draw the bounding box of text in a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     [every rectangle node/.style={draw}]
     \draw (0,0) node[rectangle] (a) {0}  ;
     \draw [->](1,-2)  -- (a);
       \node[text width=6cm, anchor=west, right] at (0,-2)
    {Index};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following image:

[image]

Is there a way to have `Index` not displayed inside a bounded rectangle? That is, I want the borders of the rectangle to be invisible.

I looked at a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170645/removing-bounding-box-of-text-node-tikz) but in my case, I still want the box to be drawn around node labelled `0`.

Comment: `\node[every rectangle node/.style={},...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do ask to `draw` all (rectangle) nodes globally applying such a style to all nodes. Probably you have a more complex picture than in your MWE, but you can always specify `draw` to only those nodes to be drawn (by default a node contour is not drawn). In your MWE this would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) node[rectangle, draw] (a) {0}  ;
        \draw [->](1,-2)  -- (a);
        \node[text width=6cm, anchor=west, right] at (0,-2)
        {Index};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If this is not feasible in your case, you can overwrite the global style on a single node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every rectangle node/.style={draw}]
        \draw (0,0) node[rectangle] (a) {0}  ;
        \draw [->](1,-2)  -- (a);
        \node[every rectangle node/.style={}, text width=6cm, anchor=west, right] at (0,-2)
        {Index};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

as Henri mentioned in [one comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673388/not-to-draw-the-bounding-box-of-text-in-a-tikz-diagram#comment1673264_673388).