# How to add text at a particular location in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-styles, text

From [TikZ Adding Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/tikz-adding-text)

I try `\node[draw,align=left] at (0.5,-6.5) {text};` But I have defined previously that `every node/.style = {draw, circle, minimum size = 7mm}`. I do not want the circle around the text. I just want plain text without any border.

Comment: In this case you can use `draw=none`. And probably you should change the title of your question to something like "How to unset the draw style for a node".

Comment: You can also use \path (0.5,-6.5) \pgfextra{\pgftext{text}}};

Comment: Please show us, what you trying so far. Example in given link has not any style definition nor circles. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Why you define common style for all nodes if than you not like that they have common style? Isn't better to define two different style?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want your node to use the settings of the `every node` style you either need to redeclare them, in this case, this will be

```
\node[rectangle, draw=none, minimum size=1pt] at (0.5, -6.5) {text};
```

since those are the default values for nodes:

- the rectangle shape,
- no drawing of the border
- and a minimum size of 1pt.

You can also reset the `every node` style only for that node by using

```
\scoped[every node/.style=]\node at (0.5, -6.5) {text};
% or
\path[every node/.style=]node at (0.5, -6.5) {text};
```

If you find yourself using that often it might by worthwhile to add

```
\tikzset{reset node/.style={every node/.style=}}
```

where `reset node` is easier to type on my Qwertz keyboard than `every node/.style=`.

This won't reset any other settings that are not set through `every node`, of course. (Simple things like `minimum size` and the `inner sep`s don't need to be set as an option to the node but can be changed anyway.